# Limit of Undo inf Rich Textbox(VB.net 2013)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How to change the undo limit of `RichTextBox`?

Can anyone help me? i have been searching for this. I created a "find all" function in my project than when runs it changes the background of matches string. and i also have a button called "Undo" when click this code runs:

```
For i = 0 To numberchanges
    rtxtContent.Undo()
Next
```

Now my problem is i think there's a limit where i can undo the `RichTextBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RichTextBox` is a .NET wrapper around the underlying Win32 `RichEdit` control. According to the [MSDN documentation for RichEdit and `EM_SETUNDOLIMIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see Remarks):

> **By default, the maximum number of actions in the undo queue is 100.** If you increase this number, there must be enough available memory to accommodate the new number. For better performance, set the limit to the smallest possible value.

So the maximum number of undo operations by default is 100. Note this is a *maximum*, not a guaranteed ability to undo 100 operations - if the operations are complex, they'll consume more of the undo buffer and it may run out of space long before that limit is reached.

You can change the limit by using `PostMessage` to send the control's window handle an `EM_SETUNDOLIMIT` message with the new desired limit. It may or may not succeed.